# ¿Funciones para reducir código?

Tags: java, funciones

Buenas noches estimados colegas, soy nuevo en el tema de funciones por lo cual en el libro que estoy leyendo para aprender a programar me piden realizar un programa usando funciones. El programa lo desarrolle  primero sin funciones y me compilo sin ningún problema pero con gran cantidad de código. Adjunto el enunciado:
Se quiere hacer un programa para administrar los alumnos de la E.S.O de un instituto,este esta compuesto por cuatro cursos y dentro de cada curso hay tres clases A,B y C. Se desea hacer un programa que permita:añadir alumnos a una clase,eliminar alumnos de una clase,informar el número de alumnos de una clase y salir del programa.Para ello os dejo la estructura que debería tener el programa:

- Añadir alumno
- Eliminar alumno
- Alumnos en clase
- Salir

**Elige una opción:**

Si elegimos 1) nos aparecerá esto:

Primero elige el curso:
Y una vez introducido por teclado aparecerá:

Ahora la clase:
Para eliminar e informar el procedimiento es el mismo pero cambiando las operaciones internas.

El programa se ejecutara hasta que el menú principal se introduzca un cuatro.

**Adjunto el código realizado:**

```
int[][] Matriz = new int[4][3];
System.out.println("Ingrese un número para interactuar con el menu (1:Añadir alumno,2:Eliminar 
    alumno, 3: Alumnos de la clase, 4: Salir)
");
Scanner tt = new Scanner(System.in);
int menu = tt.nextInt();
int c1 = 1;
int c2 = 1;
int c3 = 1;
int c4 = 1;
int c5 = 1;
int c6 = 1;
int c7 = 1;
int c8 = 1;
int c9 = 1;
int c10 = 1;
int c11 = 1;
int c12 = 1;
while (menu != 4) {
    if (menu == 1) { // Para AGREGAR ALUMNOS
        System.out.println("Primero elige el curso");
        Scanner tb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String curso = tb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ahora elige la clase ");
        Scanner th = new Scanner(System.in);
        String clase = th.nextLine();
        if ("Curso 1".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 0 && j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c1;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c1++;
        }
        if ("Curso 1".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 0 && j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c2++;
        }
        if ("Curso 1".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 0 && j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c3;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c3++;
        }
        if ("Curso 2".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 1 & j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c4;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c4++;
        }
        if ("Curso 2".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 1 & j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c5;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c5++;
        }
        if ("Curso 2".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 1 & j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c6;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c6++;
        }
        if ("Curso 3".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 2 & j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c7;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c7++;
        }
        if ("Curso 3".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 2 & j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c8;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c8++;
        }
        if ("Curso 3".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 2 & j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c9;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c9++;
        }
        if ("Curso 4".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 3 & j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c10;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c10++;
        }
        if ("Curso 4".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 3 & j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c11;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c11++;
        }
        if ("Curso 4".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 3 & j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c12;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c12++;
        }
    }

    if (menu == 2) { //PARA ELIMINAR ALUMNOS
        System.out.println("Primero elige el curso");
        Scanner tb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String curso = tb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ahora elige la clase ");
        Scanner th = new Scanner(System.in);
        String clase = th.nextLine();
        if ("Curso 1".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 0 && j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c1 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c1--;
        }
        if ("Curso 1".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 0 && j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c2 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c2--;
        }
        if ("Curso 1".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 0 && j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c3 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c3--;
        }
        if ("Curso 2".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 1 && j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c4 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c4--;
        }
        if ("Curso 2".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 1 && j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c5 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c5--;
        }
        if ("Curso 2".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 1 && j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c6 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c6--;
        }
        if ("Curso 3".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 2 && j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c7 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c7--;
        }
        if ("Curso 3".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 2 && j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c8 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c8--;
        }
        if ("Curso 3".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 2 && j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c9 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c9--;
        }
        if ("Curso 4".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 3 && j == 0) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c10 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c10--;
        }
        if ("Curso 4".equals(curso) && "B".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 3 && j == 1) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c11 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c11--;
        }
        if ("Curso 4".equals(curso) && "C".equals(clase)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                    if (x == 3 && j == 2) {
                        Matriz[x][j] = c12 - 2;
                    } else {}
                }
            }
            c12--;
        }
    }

    if (menu == 3) { //PARA MOSTRAR ALUMNOS
        for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(Matriz[x][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Ingrese un número para interactuar con el menu (1:Añadir alumno,2:Eliminar alumno,3:Alumnos de la clase, 4:Salir)");
    menu = tt.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Tu código es innecesariamente robusto, has pensado en definri funciones que usen como parámetro la clase. De esa manera habrá una sola función que funcione para todas las clases.

Comment: Veo tu código demasiado engorroso. Dado que es un ejercicio es complicado dar una respuesta óptima porque no se sabe qué puedes hacer y qué no puedes hacer. Lo propio sería manejar objetos que reflejen algo parecido a la realidad expresado en clases. De modo que habría una clase `Instituto` la cual manejaría entre otras una propiedad que sería un array de objetos de la clase `Curso` y esa clase `Curso` a su vez tendría una array de objetos de la clase `Alumno`. Luego, según las opciones elegidas irías llenando el objeto que corresponda. Toda esa lógica, por lo que veo, quieres resolverla ...

Comment: ... en el programa principal, a través de todos esos `if`, de todos esos objetos que creas al principio, etc. Por otra parte, creas varios `Scanner` sin necesidad. Un sólo `Scanner` podría servir para llevar el flujo del programa. Otra cosa, en POO no se habla de *funciones*, sino de *métodos*. Lo digo porque el término *funciones* es propio de la programación procedural, no de la POO.

Comment: Buenas noches , me agrada mucho que se tomen el tiempo para leer el problema y darme consejos para resolver mejor el programa.Como he dicho anteriormente el libro que estoy leyendo "Java y C++ Paso  a Paso " el autor hasta el momento no ha mencionado nada de POO por lo cual el se vale que el lector pueda realizar el código por medio de funciones. Muchas gracias por sus consejos tratare de leer acerca de clases y objetos para mejorar el código.

Comment: Java y C++ son lenguajes 100% orientados a objetos, por lo que para aprender dichos lenguajes tendrás que aprender sí o sí a trabajar con objetos, lo cual a su vez  te facilitará de una forma increíble resolver el problema que ha sido planteado en la pregunta. La POO ayuda mucho a emprender la solución del problema pensando en la vida real: **en un `Instituto` hay varios objetos del tipo `Curso` y en esos cursos hay varios objetos del tipo `Alumno`**. Esa es la clave de todo, si no lo expresas así en tu programa, rápido te encuentras perdido en el código.

Comment: Por favor incluye la forma en que has intentado pasarlo a funciones, de esa manera será más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que es un funcion? es una forma de optimizar tu codigo, de forma tal que cosas que tengas que hacer de forma repetitiva (te suena en tu codigo?) puedan ser extraidas del mismo para que sean ejecutadas de la misma forma (te suena?) pero con una sola porcion de codigo...

O sea.. sin mirar tu ejercicio exactamente, pero mirando tu codigo, veo muchas secciones repetitivas...

Esto que sigue es una analisis puro de codigo (sin importar como es tu ejercicio)..

---

**NOTA**

En los comentarios hablan de POO y es totalmente correcto. Pero yo opino que es correcto primero aprender funciones y luego ir para POO, al fin y al cabo, POO no es mas que el encapsulamiento de funciones dentro de otro paradigma...

---

Ahora si, analicemos tu codigo:

Sin entrar en los detalles si las formas son correctas.. veo por ejemplo que si se selecciona menu 1, entonces haces 12 veces lo siguiente:

```
if ("Curso 1".equals(curso) && "A".equals(clase)) {
    for (int x = 0; x < Matriz.length; x++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[x].length; j++) {
            if (x == 0 && j == 0) {
                Matriz[x][j] = c1;
            } else {}
        }
    }
    c1++;
}
```

O sea.. si hacemos 12 veces lo mismo (o similar, ya vas a ver) entonces esto es un gran candidato a una funcion!!!!

en nuestro caso.. el codigo ni siquiera es logico del todo (no tiene logica recorrer una matriz para solo cambiar un item, mejor ir y cambiarlo directamente), pero suponiendo que estuviera bien (que no lo esta), pongamoslo en una funcion...

```
public int ActualizarMatriz(string curso, string clase, int[][] Matriz, int cantidad) {
    int x = 0;
    int j = 0;
    switch (curso.toLowerCase()) {
        case "curso 1":
            x = 1;
            break;
        case "curso 2":
            x = 2;
            break;
        ...etc...
    }
    // hacemos lo mismo con la clase
    switch (curso.toLowerCase()) {
        case "a":
            j = 1;
            break;
        ...etc...
    }
    // Aca vendria tu for, que no hace nada.. mejor cambiar directamente lo que sabemos que queremos cambiar
    matriz[x][j] = cantidad;
    return cantidad++;
}
```

Esta funcion retorna la nueva cantidad.. la matriz cambia sola, porque pasa por referencia (lee sobre como pasan las variables a funciones), pero como cantidad pasa por valor, hay que devolverlo (o decirle que lo pase como referencia)...

Entonces, fijate, tu codigo de llamada ahora seria:

```
if (menu == 1) { // Para AGREGAR ALUMNOS
    System.out.println("Primero elige el curso");
    Scanner tb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String curso = tb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ahora elige la clase ");
    Scanner th = new Scanner(System.in);
    String clase = th.nextLine();
    c1 = ActualizarMatriz(curso, clase, Matriz, c1);
```

Peroooooo... tenemos un problema... estamos pasando siempre c1.. y eso porque? porque en lugar de guardar los valores en la matriz (como realmente estas haciendo) los estas guardando en 12 variables, lo cual es raro, porque para eso tenemos la matriz no????

Entonces, mejor, usar directamente la matriz que para eso esta....

Esto es solo un ejemplo, de como usar una funcion para mejorar tu codigo, y con todo lo que tenes que trabajar.

Creo que queda claro que tenes que reever todo tu codigo, y que solo te explico como se podria refactorizar tu codigo usando funciones, en base a tu propio codigo...

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, voy a tomar todos tus consejos y volver a codificar empleando solo funciones.Tratare de mejorar el problema de los contadores(usando la matriz como usted lo menciono).